# Conditional filtering of dataframe – TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get some data from "Year" columns

that is `"22 < x < 100"`

and I made this code

```
df4 = df_y[[df_y["Year"]<100] & [df_y['Year']>22]]
```

but that doesn't work with this error

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'"

what can i do...?

Comment: Use () instead of [] for & operation

Comment: holy.... i love ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df4 = df_y[(df_y["Year"]<100) & (df_y['Year']>22)]
```

Use `()` instead of `[]` for `&` operation